# Laravel 7.x ResetsPasswords

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm following a tutorial for rest the password in laravel via API, the problem is that laravel 7.x doesn't have `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;` and I can't find any solution online

And I can't find it here:

https://laravel.com/api/7.x/search.html?search=ResetsPasswords

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have Auth installed in your project?  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#introduction

Comment: Yes, I have it installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Trait that you're looking for has been removed from the core Laravel framework repository and into a separate package called `laravel/ui`.

You need to install it via `composer require laravel/ui`. The namespace in your use statement should be the same `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the file in the following directory.
I don't know how it is called from ResetPasswordController.php but it is called from it.

vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).